# Launching node application's with webpack: error cross-env NODE_ENV=development node src

Tags: mysql, reactjs, webpack, redux

Fairly new to webdev and I want to run this person's code:

https://github.com/RaidVisat/template-ract-redux-orm-sqlz-ssr

Not familiar with webpack yet, and I've tried every route of npm install/start with no success.

Also, I tried the start command in the package.json file: "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node src" and did not have success.

(Also, pretty sure I have all the proper global packages installed, could be wrong tho.)

Currently getting this error:

> cross-env NODE_ENV=development node src

sh: cross-env: command not found
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! nde05@0.0.0 start: `cross-env NODE_ENV=development node src`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the nde05@0.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

Comment: did you install https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env ?

Comment: Ahh, this worked, I ended up installing node-sass as well as cross-env. Thank you so much!